# Removing XML nodes From XML Using JaVa

Tags: java, xml, parsing, nodes

I have a XML document

```
<ns1:Product>
<ns1:ProductDetails>
    <ns1:StationID>1</ns1:StationID>
    <ns1:ProductGroup>1</ns1:ProductGroup>
    <ns1:AccountCode>1</ns1:AccountCode>
    <ns1:Amount>1345</ns1:Amount>
    </ns1:ProductDetails>
<ns1:ProductDetails>
    <ns1:StationID>1</ns1:StationID>
    <ns1:ProductGroup>1</ns1:ProductGroup>
    <ns1:AccountCode>2</ns1:AccountCode>
    <ns1:Amount>35471</ns1:Amount>
    </ns1:ProductDetails>
<ns1:ProductDetails>
    <ns1:StationID>1</ns1:StationID>
    <ns1:ProductGroup>1</ns1:ProductGroup>
    <ns1:AccountCode>3</ns1:AccountCode>
    <ns1:Amount>31897</ns1:Amount>
    </ns1:ProductDetails>
<ns1:ProductDetails>
    <ns1:StationID>1</ns1:StationID>
    <ns1:ProductGroup>1</ns1:ProductGroup>
    <ns1:AccountCode>4</ns1:AccountCode>
    <ns1:Amount>143647</ns1:Amount>
    </ns1:ProductDetails>
<ns1:ProductDetails>
    <ns1:StationID>1</ns1:StationID>
    <ns1:ProductGroup>1</ns1:ProductGroup>
    <ns1:AccountCode>5</ns1:AccountCode>
    <ns1:Amount>34531</ns1:Amount>
</ns1:ProductDetails>
```

I have able to count the total number of records using Java as 5. I have few requirement in which i have to remove some records before processing further. Say for example I have to remove 3rd and 5th ProductDetails from the XML

Base on the record Position details I have to remove the 2 record

Final Output

```
<ns1:Product>
<ns1:ProductDetails>
    <ns1:StationID>1</ns1:StationID>
    <ns1:ProductGroup>1</ns1:ProductGroup>
    <ns1:AccountCode>1</ns1:AccountCode>
    <ns1:Amount>1345</ns1:Amount>
</ns1:ProductDetails>
<ns1:ProductDetails>
    <ns1:StationID>1</ns1:StationID>
    <ns1:ProductGroup>1</ns1:ProductGroup>
    <ns1:AccountCode>2</ns1:AccountCode>
    <ns1:Amount>35471</ns1:Amount>
</ns1:ProductDetails>
<ns1:ProductDetails>
    <ns1:StationID>1</ns1:StationID>
    <ns1:ProductGroup>1</ns1:ProductGroup>
    <ns1:AccountCode>4</ns1:AccountCode>
    <ns1:Amount>143647</ns1:Amount>
    </ns1:ProductDetails>
 </ns1:Product>
```

Can some one please help be to active this in Java Code!

Comment: Show us what have you tried and where did you stuck and we'll help you to move on. I'd use DOM to create a document object model and then you can add/remove nodes in model. Then you can write DOM to file again. There is a tutorial googled right now: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html

Comment: See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3717875/383861

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard library. I'm sorry but you've got to read the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html) :

> "To remove a node, you use its parent Node's removeChild method."