# remove element from xml file in java [for my data xml]

Tags: java, xml

I have this XML file

[image]

I need function in Java which can remove the `username` node.

I use function `remove()`

```
public void remove(String username){
    // what do I write here to remove node of the username?
}
```

For example I need to remove element "anas":

```
remove("anas")
```

and the result is

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also take a look at JAXB Examples on Java tutorials http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/examples.html

Comment: thnx for replay , but i need code for my data plz

Comment: I hope this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717215/remove-xml-node-using-java-parser

Comment: I almost always automatically downvote when I see `i need code for my data plz`. Show some effort.

Comment: thnx but this remove by node , not by contain the node
i need someone programming to me a code function remove of my data

Comment: plz i need anther way

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
package com.sree;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document document = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(
                new File("input.xml"));

        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expression = xpath
                .compile("//data/user/username[text()='simple']");
        Node b13Node = (Node) expression
                .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
        b13Node = b13Node.getParentNode();
        b13Node.getParentNode().removeChild(b13Node);

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        t.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));
    }

}
```