# remove xml node based on node number using java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, xmlnode

Here i have xml structure as

```
<book>  <!--node 0-->
    <id>1111</id>
    <name>abacd</name>
    <author>abcd</author>
    <price>700</price>
    <category>abcd</category>       
</book>                       
<book>  <!--node 1-->
    <id>2222</id>
    <name>abacd</name>
    <author>abcd</author>
    <price>700</price>
    <category>abcd</category>       
</book>  
<book>  <!--node 2-->
    <id>3333</id>
    <name>abacd</name>
    <author>abcd</author>
    <price>700</price>
    <category>abcd</category>       
</book>
```

Based on node number i need to delete that node entirely.
I'm able to get node number and all child nodes but i dont know how to deltet,can anybody guide me how to do it.eg:node 0. has to delete.
This is what i tried to delet node 0 :

```
File fXmlFile = new File(xmlfilePath);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");
    Node nNode = nList.item(Integer.parseInt(nodeNumber));
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
         Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        String id = eElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent();
         if ((id.equals(bookId))) {
            eElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).removeChild(nNode);
        }
    }
```

please help me to get desired output.

Comment: here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717215/remove-xml-node-using-java-parser

Comment: @ppuskar,i dont want to use XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("//A/B[C/E/text()=13]"); please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is missing a root element. Here my corrected version:

```
<root>
<book>  <!--node 0 -->
    <id>1111</id>
    <name>abacd</name>
    <author>abcd</author>
    <price>700</price>
    <category>abcd</category>
</book>
<book>  <!--node 1 -->
    <id>2222</id>
    <name>abacd</name>
    <author>abcd</author>
    <price>700</price>
    <category>abcd</category>
</book>
<book>  <!--node 2 -->
    <id>3333</id>
    <name>abacd</name>
    <author>abcd</author>
    <price>700</price>
    <category>abcd</category>
</book>
```

Here a JUnit test using [XMLBeam](http://xmlbeam.org)

```
public class DeleteNodeTest {

public interface Books {
    @XBDelete("//book[id=$PARAM0]")
    int deleteBooks(int id);
}

@Test
public void deleteNode() throws IOException {
    Books books = new XBProjector(Flags.TO_STRING_RENDERS_XML).io().url("resource://test.xml").read(Books.class);
    System.out.println("Deleted " + books.deleteBooks(1111) + " nodes.");
    System.out.println(books);
}
```

}

This program prints out:

```
Deleted 1 nodes.
```

```
<book>  <!--node 1 -->
    <id>2222</id>
    <name>abacd</name>
    <author>abcd</author>
    <price>700</price>
    <category>abcd</category>
</book>
<book>  <!--node 2 -->
    <id>3333</id>
    <name>abacd</name>
    <author>abcd</author>
    <price>700</price>
    <category>abcd</category>
</book>
```